# Spotfire and Regex- Finding $ Amounts in Strings

Tags: regex, spotfire

I'm wondering if there is a way to extract a dollar value from a string using a calculated  RXExtract column. Here are *some* examples of data that I'm dealing with:

```
[Ticket Description]
1. "51 hrs @ $1,000 per/HR 5.5"-----Goal: $1000
2. "5.5" EXC cost $200/DAY"----- Goal: $200
3. "Open Top - $275/DAY"------ Goal: $275
4. "Trash Rental ($100/DAY)"-----Goal: $100
```

Not super knowledgeable with Regex and I've done some research, but can't figure out how to separate the "$" value from the string. Thinking the expression could be something like '^($+)$' , but isn't working on my end. Any help/advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$`: `RXExtract([Column 2],"\\$[0-9]+",1)`

[image]

### Edit for updated question:

if thousand separator can be part of the number, then need to update 2nd attribute of the formula:
`"\\$[0-9,]+"`
(in case decimal separator is also valid, `.` can be added too)

Comment: This seems to work in some of the cases, but isn't grabbing the full dollar value. Example: "Hrs @ $1,050 per/hr" is extracting "$1".

Comment: I also need it to disregard examples 1 and 2, where numbers were listed before the dollar values.

Comment: "Hrs @ $1,050 per/hr" - please update your question with all valid number formats, so I can update my answer. "I also need it to disregard examples 1 and 2, where numbers were listed before the dollar values." - is the output of my formula incorrect? if yes, please share desired output.

Comment: Yes, if there are numbers that exist before the "$" symbol, those need to be disregarded. Ultimately we want to find the "$" value from the string. Numbers or items before the "$" amount may be there for descriptive reasons. The idea you've provided works in some cases, but not all. Your idea is extremely close and your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `[0-9]` - this won't match `1,000` with that thousands separator in there. Adding the comma into the group, `[0-91]` would be the easiest way to fix that - if getting the result `$1,000` is okay here (in the question it said that should be `$1000`, but right now can't tell if requirement, or typo.)

Comment: @AnnonymousAsker numbers before $ are already excluded. (as well as numbers after $ but in different word), I still struggle to understand where it doesn't work.